# uninitialized constant UsersController using devise in Production while signing out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I can't sign_out in production with Devise. In development, everything works fine. I think the delete doesn't work in production for Devise. I know the workaround with changing the `config.sign_out_via = :delete` to `:get` in devise.rb but I don't want to do this as I read this introduces vulnerabilities. Also, when I try to perform delete action to users/30/clients/23 in development it works fine but in production I get an error that says

> The action 'show' could not be found for ClientsController

So, I think this has something to do with delete method only as signing up, signing in work fine in production as well.

How do I proceed?

Comment: Changing link_to to button_to worked but I don't get why link_to doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`link_to` will generate a GET request, `button_to` will generate a POST request - both need different routes and go to different actions. Your link goes to:

- show action with GET request (with id provided)
- create action with POST request
- destroy action with POST request and a hidden _method parameter value set to DELETE - that's because delete method is not supported in modern browsers (nor in HTML5 - more about it [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114156/why-are-there-are-no-put-and-delete-methods-on-html-forms/264735))

You can force `link_to` to use POST method though:

`<%= link_to "Your link", your_path, method: :post %>`